# Radix sorts in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

I was curious, how in-place radix sort compares to the variant which uses an auxiliary array in order to speed up the sorting. I implemented both and tested it against `java.util.Arrays.sort(int[])`.

> ```
> Seed: 1439451337582
> Radixsort.InPlace.sort in 12074 milliseconds.
> Radixsort.sort in 6937 milliseconds.
> Arrays.sort in 16316 milliseconds.
> Arrays identical: true
> ```

What do you think?

**Radixsort.java:**

```java
package net.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * This class implements a radix sort using an auxiliary array in order to speed
 * up sorting.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 */
public class Radixsort {

    /**
     * The byte index of the most significant byte in each 32-bit integer.
     */
    private static final int MOST_SIGNIFICANT_BYTE_INDEX = 3;

    /**
     * The mask for manipulating the sign bit.
     */
    private static final int SIGN_BIT_MASK = 0x8000_0000;

    /**
     * The amount of bits per byte.
     */
    private static final int BITS_PER_BYTE = 8;

    /**
     * The mask for extracting the bucket index.
     */
    private static final int EXTRACT_BYTE_MASK = 0xff;

    /**
     * The amount of buckets considered for sorting.
     */
    private static final int BUCKET_AMOUNT = 256;

    /**
     * If the range length is less than this constant use 
     * {@link java.util.Arrays.sort} and exit.
     */
    private static final int QUICKSORT_THRESHOLD = 128;

    /**
     * This inner static class provides an in-place implementation of the radix
     * sort.
     */
    public static final class InPlace {

        /**
         * Sorts the range {@code array[fromIndex], array[fromIndex + 1], ...,
         * array[toIndex - 2], array[toIndex - 1]}.
         * 
         * @param array     the array holding the target range.
         * @param fromIndex the starting, inclusive index of the range.
         * @param toIndex   the ending, exclusive index of the range.
         */
        public static void sort(int[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
            if (toIndex - fromIndex < 2) {
                return;
            }

            sort(array, fromIndex, toIndex, MOST_SIGNIFICANT_BYTE_INDEX);
        }

        /**
         * Sorts the entire array.
         * 
         * @param array the array to sort.
         */
        public static void sort(int[] array) {
            sort(array, 0, array.length);
        }

        private static void sort(int[] array, 
                                 int fromIndex,
                                 int toIndex,
                                 int byteIndex) {
            if (toIndex - fromIndex < QUICKSORT_THRESHOLD) {
                Arrays.sort(array, fromIndex, toIndex);
                return;
            }

            int[] bucketSizeMap = new int[BUCKET_AMOUNT];

            // Count the size of each bucket.
            for (int i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; ++i) {
                bucketSizeMap[getBucketIndex(array[i], byteIndex)]++;
            }

            // Compute the map mapping each bucket into its start index.
            int[] startIndexMap = new int[BUCKET_AMOUNT];
            startIndexMap[0] = fromIndex;

            for (int i = 1; i < BUCKET_AMOUNT; ++i) {
                startIndexMap[i] = startIndexMap[i - 1] + bucketSizeMap[i - 1];
            }

            int[] processedMap = new int[BUCKET_AMOUNT];
            boolean[] bucketReadyMap = new boolean[BUCKET_AMOUNT];

            // Now move the elements to their proper buckets.
            for (int index = fromIndex; index < toIndex;) {
                int element = array[index];
                int elementBucketIndex = getBucketIndex(element, byteIndex);
                int targetIndex = startIndexMap[elementBucketIndex] +
                                   processedMap[elementBucketIndex];

                if (bucketReadyMap[elementBucketIndex] 
                        || index == targetIndex) {
                    ++index;
                } else {
                    int tmp = array[targetIndex];
                    array[targetIndex] = element;
                    array[index] = tmp;
                    processedMap[elementBucketIndex]++;
                }

                if (processedMap[elementBucketIndex] 
                        == bucketSizeMap[elementBucketIndex]) {
                    bucketReadyMap[elementBucketIndex] = true;
                }
            }

            // Recur to sorting the buckets.
            if (byteIndex > 0) {
                // If more bytes are available, recursively sort the buckets.
                for (int i = 0; i < BUCKET_AMOUNT; ++i) {
                    if (bucketSizeMap[i] != 0) {
                        sort(array, 
                             startIndexMap[i],
                             startIndexMap[i] + bucketSizeMap[i],
                             byteIndex - 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the range {@code array[fromIndex], array[fromIndex + 1], ...,
     * array[toIndex - 2], array[toIndex - 1]}.
     * 
     * @param array     the array holding the target range.
     * @param fromIndex the starting, inclusive index of the range.
     * @param toIndex   the ending, exclusive index of the range.
     */
    public static void sort(int[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        if (toIndex - fromIndex < 2) {
            return;
        }

        sort(array,
             Arrays.copyOfRange(array, fromIndex, toIndex), 
             fromIndex,
             0,
             toIndex - fromIndex,
             MOST_SIGNIFICANT_BYTE_INDEX);
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the entire array.
     * 
     * @param array the array to sort.
     */
    public static void sort(int[] array) {
        sort(array, 0, array.length);
    }

    private static void sort(int[] source, 
                             int[] target,
                             int sourceOffset,
                             int targetOffset,
                             int rangeLength,
                             int byteIndex) {
        if (rangeLength < QUICKSORT_THRESHOLD) {
            Arrays.sort(source, sourceOffset, sourceOffset + rangeLength);

            if ((byteIndex & 1) == 0) {
                System.arraycopy(source, 
                                 sourceOffset, 
                                 target, 
                                 targetOffset, 
                                 rangeLength);
            }

            return;
        }

        int[] bucketSizeMap = new int[BUCKET_AMOUNT];

        // Count the size of each bucket.
        for (int i = sourceOffset; i < sourceOffset + rangeLength; ++i) {
            bucketSizeMap[getBucketIndex(source[i], byteIndex)]++;
        }

        // Compute the map mapping each bucket to its beginning index.
        int[] startIndexMap = new int[BUCKET_AMOUNT];

        for (int i = 1; i < BUCKET_AMOUNT; ++i) {
            startIndexMap[i] = startIndexMap[i - 1] + bucketSizeMap[i - 1];
        }

        // The map mapping each bucket index to amount of elements already put
        // in the bucket.
        int[] processedMap = new int[BUCKET_AMOUNT];

        for (int i = sourceOffset; i < sourceOffset + rangeLength; ++i) {
            int element = source[i];
            int bucket = getBucketIndex(element, byteIndex);
            target[targetOffset + startIndexMap[bucket] + 
                                   processedMap[bucket]++] = element;
        }

        if (byteIndex > 0) {
            // Recursively sort the buckets.
            for (int i = 0; i < BUCKET_AMOUNT; ++i) {
                if (bucketSizeMap[i] != 0) {
                    sort(target, 
                         source, 
                         targetOffset + startIndexMap[i],
                         sourceOffset + startIndexMap[i], 
                         bucketSizeMap[i], 
                         byteIndex - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the bucket index for {@code element} when considering 
     * {@code byteIndex}th byte within the element. The indexing starts from
     * the least significant bytes.
     * 
     * @param element   the element for which to compute the bucket index.
     * @param byteIndex the index of the byte to be considered.
     * @return the bucket index.
     */
    private static int getBucketIndex(int element, int byteIndex) {
        return ((byteIndex == MOST_SIGNIFICANT_BYTE_INDEX ? 
                 element ^ SIGN_BIT_MASK :
                 element) >>> (byteIndex * BITS_PER_BYTE)) & EXTRACT_BYTE_MASK;
    }

}
```

**Demo.java:**

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import net.coderodde.util.Radixsort;

/**
 * This class implements a demonstration comparing the performance of the radix
 * sorts.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 */
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Random random = new Random(seed);

        int[] array1 = getRandomIntegerArray(100000000, random);
        int[] array2 = array1.clone();
        int[] array3 = array1.clone();

        System.out.println("Seed: " + seed);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Radixsort.InPlace.sort(array1, 3, array1.length - 4);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Radixsort.InPlace.sort in " + (endTime - startTime) + 
                           " milliseconds.");

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Radixsort.sort(array2, 3, array2.length - 4);
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Radixsort.sort in " + (endTime - startTime) +
                           " milliseconds.");

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Arrays.sort(array3, 3, array2.length - 4);
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Arrays.sort in " + (endTime - startTime) + 
                           " milliseconds.");

        System.out.println("Arrays identical: " + 
                (Arrays.equals(array1, array2) && 
                 Arrays.equals(array2, array3)));
    }

    private static int[] getRandomIntegerArray(int size, Random random) {
        return IntStream.range(0, size).map((a) -> random.nextInt()).toArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have thought the out-of-place sort would use a LSB algorithm, which would be faster than the MSB algorithm.

Comment: In order to qualify the inPlace vs outPlace, we would need to evaluate the memory costs :) Repeat the tests with hundreds of arrays of various sizes, so that the garbage collector start hurting. Then compare :)

Comment: Care to include a statement about the stability of `InPlace.sort(int[])`?

Comment: @greybeard Not relevant since `int`s are not objects.

Answer (score 2):

Not much to say about this lovely well-documented code, it's very well written. Just some notes:

> ```
> private static int getBucketIndex(int element, int byteIndex) {
>     return ((byteIndex == MOST_SIGNIFICANT_BYTE_INDEX ? 
>              element ^ SIGN_BIT_MASK :
>              element) >>> (byteIndex * BITS_PER_BYTE)) & EXTRACT_BYTE_MASK;
> }
> ```

The return statement looks ugly and hard to read. Turn it into an `if` statement:

```
private static int getBucketIndex(int element, int byteIndex) {
    int result = element;
    if (byteIndex == MOST_SIGNIFICANT_BYTE_INDEX) {
        result ^= SIGN_BIT_MASK;
    }
    return (result >>> (byteIndex * BITS_PER_BYTE)) & EXTRACT_BYTE_MASK;
}
```